# Do I need to have different SSH key pairs if I want to connect to 2 different remote servers?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am new to this SSH thing and I know my machine has already generated ssh key pairs in the past to connect to a server. If I want to connect to different server in different network, do I need to generate separate key pair and save them in separate folders? How can I do that? How can I select which key I use when I am connecting to the server?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same key pair for two servers. You just copy over the public portion of your keyset to both machines and add it to the `authorized_keys` file.

```
scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub remote.server.com:
ssh remote.server.com cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Afterwards you can delete `id_rsa.pub` from the remote server

It is also worth noting that you can specify the private key on the command line when running ssh with the `-i` switch: 
`ssh -i .ssh/keyForServer1.rsa remote.host.com`

If you don't have a id_rsa.pub in your .ssh directory, then you can generate a new key pair:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

This will create your private key, `id_rsa` which you should never copy anywhere as it is equivalent to your password, and `id_rsa.pub` which you copy to remote servers. I recommend skimming through the manpage for `ssh-keygen` as it has some useful options

---

**Note**: Some systems, notably systems running older versions of OpensSSH, use `.ssh/authorized_keys2` instead

Comment: Hi @Jarmund, thanks! What I don't understand here is that inside my .ssh folder, I have 3 files, which are authorized_keys, known_hosts, and known_hosts.old. I don't see any id_rsa or id_rsa.pub. Inside my authorized_keys, I have "ssh-rsa [XX] [admin_account]" where I suppose [XX] is the key.

Comment: @eng2019 `known_hosts` is a way for your computer to to keep tabs on the identity of other machines. It has one line for each machine you've ever shelled into. `authorized_keys` contains a list of public keys whos matching private key is allowed to log in as your user on your machine. as for `id_rsa.pub`, you most likely need to generate it (or put it there, if you've already generated it and placed it elsewhere). I've added details about generating the key-pair in my answer.

Comment: You need to quote `ssh [user@]remote 'cat pubkey >>.ssh/authorized_keys'` so it happens on the remote machine not locally. Or most systems have `ssh-copy-id` which manages this for you.

Answer (score 0):

SSH server uses Public - Private key pair as an authentication mechanism. The client generates a key pair, the private key remains with the client, and the public key needs to be placed within the `Authorized_keys` file in the server machine, generally within the `.ssh` folder placed within the home profile of the user on the server machine.

When you connect via SSH, you take on the security profile of the user you have logged in as, the same user in whose home folder (`.ssh -> Authorized_keys`) you placed the public key.

On the client side, that is, your own machine, you will have `known_hosts` file, which keeps a tab on `ssh` servers which you have previously connected to.

When you connect to a `SSH server` for the first time, you are generally prompted with a message asking if you trust the server to which you are attempting a connection, if yes, the server's details are added to the `known_hosts` file.

In your question, you have indicated that your machine, intended to be used as a client, has already generated a key pair. You can take the public key of that key pair, and place it in the `Authorized_keys` file, in any number of servers. Just ensure that, on the server side, in the `sshd_config` file, the server is enabled to use Key pair authentication. On your machine, if using a `GUI SSH client`, you can select authentication mechanism as key pair, and browse and select the `private key`, or if using command line, then

`ssh -i .ssh/<your_private_key> sshserver.com`

Comment: Public key goes into `authorized_keys`, not private.

Comment: Oops, bit of a typo. Thanks.